# How to properly inject fragments for a single activity App

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm using dagger2 in my project. Project follows MVP pattern. My app design is like I'm using a single activity
throught my application. All UI elemets are in Fragments and the single activity acts as the 
host activity for all the fragments in the project. Each module in my project will be using a 
fragment as the UI component like LoginFragment, SplashScreenFragment,RegistrationFragment, HomeScreenFragment.

So basically my activity will be launched only once, and it contains a fragment container only, where fragments will be replaced
when user navigates to each screens in each module.

each time user moves from one screen to another, instead of creating an activity it , It will just invoke a `gotoNextScreen`
in the activity, which will then inflate the next fragment

So My activity will be doing the following operations only

- Receiving next screen type to be launched
- Finding which fragment to be inflated from the launching screen type
  from intent
- create fragment(which acts as the view layer in MVP) and presenter
  for the screen
- link presenter and fragment (or view)
- perform the fragment transaction.

Since I have `n` number of screens (`n` number of fragmetns and presenters), I cannot  use field 
injection on activity like

```
            public class MainActivity{
                @Inject RegistrationFragment registrationFragment;
                @Inject LoginFragment loginFragment
            }
```

because the number of field will be huge, also at a time we need only one fragment 
and one presenter. So what I did is , I created seperate components for each module ,
made it as a dependent component of my main App component. Now my activity looks like this.

```
            public void gotoNextScreen(ScreenType screentype, Data data){

                        switch(screentype){
                            case LOGIN:
                                 DaggerLoginComponent.builder()
                                                .appComponent(mAppComponent)                        
                                                .build();
                                 // get login fragment and presenter from login component and inflate               
                                 break;

                            case REGISTRATION:
                                 DaggerLoginComponent.builder()
                                                .appComponent(mAppComponent)                        
                                                .build();
                               // get registration fragment and presenter from registration component and inflate               

                             // and the switch case goes on like this

                        }
        }
```

I find it very difficult because I'm almost repeating the code in each and every module.
Im creating different components just for different fragmet types and presenters.

Can I simplify using generics or something like that? Does dagger provide any simple way to solve this kind 
of problem? Can anyone show some sample code to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the right approach either as I'm quite new with Dagger2 and MVP too but I've implemented it like that:

The Fragment has a callback to the Activity as explained in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

The callback as a `gotoNextScreen` method.
The `goToNextScreen` (implemented by the Activity), calls the Activity presenter.

This presenter is in charge of instantiating the Fragment and call a `displayFragment` method on the View (the Activity). Like that the Activity doesn't know anything about the implementation. It just passes the information to the presenter and then display the Fragment.

It look like that:

**FragmentA**

```
public void onNext(){
   mActivityCallback.gotoNextScreen(screentype, data);
}
```

**The Activity**

```
public void gotoNextScreen(ScreenType screentype, Data data){
   mPresenter.goToNext(screentype, data);
}

public void displayFragment(Fragment f){
   // Code to replace the current Fragment by the fragment f
}
```

**The Activity Presenter**

```
public void goToNext(ScreenType screentype, Data data){
   Fragment f;
   switch(screentype){
      case A:
          f = FragmentA.newInstance(data);
          break;
      case B:
          f = FragmentB.newInstance(data);
          break;
      ...
   }
   mView.displayFragment(f); // mView is the Activity
}
```

As I said, I'm not sure this implementation is valid as:

- You have 2 times the same `gotoNextScreen` method (in the Activity and the Presenter)
- The presenter deals with Fragment (which are Android objects).
- The Fragment is not injected.

**EDIT**

Dagger part:

The Activity is injected when created:

```
MainActivityComponent component = ((CustomApplication) getApplication()).getComponent()
                .plus(new MainActivityModule());
```

Same with the Fragment:

The callback to the activity has a `getComponent` method and when the Fragment is attached, it calls:

```
public void onAttach(Context context) {
   //...
    activityCallback.getComponent().inject(FragmentA.this)
}
```

Comment: Your solution I understood and I'm doing it almost in the same way. But my question was basically regarding the dagger setup in this kind of a situation.

Comment: I've edited my answer with Dagger implement. The Fragment has its own Component, Module, Presenter and Model

Comment: I have more than one Activity in my app so I'm using a global component managed by the Application class. That why I do `component.plus(module)` . But as you have only one Activity I think it can manage the component directly